# Sending JSON from python to Flask using request with no results

Tags: python, json, flask

I try to run small meet station on Arduino, in fact it is already can monitor temperature and humidity. So I decided to store data in DB and visualise ob web server using Flask. I create small script on python which get data from serial and send it to server.

```
def send_JSON_to_server(meteodata):
    print(meteodata)
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/meteo'
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    resp = requests.post(url , data = json.dumps(meteodata), headers=headers)
    print(resp)

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem1411', 9600)
while True:
    json_string = ser.readline().decode("utf-8")   
    send_JSON_to_server(json_string)
```

And it get data perforated string from serial port and try to send it Flask app. On server side I have a code:

```
@app.route('/api/meteo/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def save_meteo_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.json:
            json_dict = request.get_json()
            save_meteo_data_to_db(json_dict)
            return 200
    else:
        return render_template('test.html'), 999
```

And here I got a problem, it seems to me that request come to server as GET, at least if I left only POST in methods, I immediately get 405 response and no error in apache log. If I left it like this request send to server and return 999, which means that it was not accepted as POST. I know that 405 is usually connected to configuration or security issue, so you can see my virtual host configuration bellow. I use the same in different project and it is working.

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/meteo/meteo.wsgi

DocumentRoot /var/www/meteo
    <Directory /var/www/meteo>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

I also want to provide example of JSON which I get from Arduino and response after requests.post, as you can see bellow.

```
{"humidity":57.10,"temperature":28.10,"tempbyfeeling":29.27}

<Response [405]>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find out a stupid mistake in my Flask app, during routing you can see the line:

```
@app.route('/api/meteo/', methods=['GET','POST'])
```

and here is a mistake which lead to response 301 and immediately generate GET. The right line should be:

```
@app.route('/api/meteo', methods=['GET','POST'])
```

One / need to be deleted thats all.